# Let $f(z)$ be an entire function such that $|f(z)| > |z|$ for every $z \in \mathbb{C}$

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm just having trouble with this function.

Let $f(z)$ be an entire function such that $|f(z)| > |z|$ for every $z \in \mathbb{C}$

How would I for example prove that it does not exist an  $z_0 \in \mathbb{C}$ such that $f(z_0) = 0$

Comment: That's easy: $|0| > |z_0|$ is impossible.

Comment: Thanks you! I can see that with the plots, but how would I write that in more detailed language.

Comment: Can an absolute value ever be negative?

Comment: You could assume that there exists such $z_0$ and arrive at a contradiction. It should be easy using the argument from the previous comments.

Comment: If you meant $\ge |z|$ then $\frac{1}{f(z)}$ is meromorphic and $g(z)= \frac{z}{f(z)}$ is bounded, thus it is entire and constant.